# Facebook FQL: find friends whose location is within a certain range of coordinates

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, latitude-longitude

hope someone can help. Am pretty new to this...

I'm trying to use FQL to return a list of friends who are within a certain distance of a specific latitude and longitude. So far I've got:

> SELECT uid, name, current_location FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())

Which returns the lat and long of each friend. So far, so good. However I only want to return results within, say, 30km of latitude 52.2500, longitude -0.8833.

Can I even do this with FQL?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that FQL doesn't have cos/sin/tan functions this isn't possible without doing the calculations before for the bounding area.

See http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates